# Chaining of function and bifunction in java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-programming

Java-8 comes with `Function` and `BiFunction`. How we can chain multiple `Function` or `Bifunction` instances. So that output of one become input of another `Function`. I've created simple functions and Bifunctions to illustrate.

```
import java.util.function.BiFunction;
import java.util.function.Function;

class FunctionSample1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> mul = (x, y) -> {
            return x * y;
        };

        BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> div = (x, y) -> {
            return x / y;
        };

        BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> sum = (x, y) -> {
            return x + y;
        };

        BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> sub = (x, y) -> {
            return x - y;
        };

        Function<Integer, Integer> mulfunc = (y) -> {
            return y * 9;
        };

        Function<Integer, Integer> divfunc = (y) -> {
            return y / 2;
        };

        Function<Integer, Integer> sumfunc = (y) -> {
            return y + 89;
        };

        Function<Integer, Integer> subdunc = (y) -> {
            return y - 2;
        };
    }
}
```

How can I chain them whether using `compose` or `andThen` for getting the result ?

Answer (score 9):

Both `Function` and `BiFunction` have a method [`andThen(Function)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Function.html#andThen(java.util.function.Function)) to let you build composed functions.

```
BiFunction.andThen(Function) = BiFunction
Function.andThen(Function) = Function
```

For example,

```
BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> mul = (x, y) -> x * y;
Function<Integer, Integer> times2 = x -> x * 2;
Function<Integer, Integer> minus1 = x -> x - 1;

// r = ((3 * 3) * 2) - 1
Integer r = mul.andThen(times2).andThen(minus1).apply(3, 3);
```

---

`Function` also has a method [`compose(Function)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Function.html#compose(java.util.function.Function)).

```
Function1.compose(Function0) = Function0.andThen(Function1) = Function
```

For example,

```
// r2 = (3 - 1) * 2
Integer r2 = times2.compose(minus1).apply(3);
```

Comment: Can a `Function` `.andThen()` a `BiFunction`?

Comment: @AustinSchäfer No, `Function` returns a single value, `BiFunction` takes two values

Comment: Well, it would make sense if we had methods like `default <V> BiFunction<V,U,R> composeFirst(Function<V,T> f) { return (v,u) -> apply(f.apply(v), u); }` and `default <V> BiFunction<T,V,R> composeSecond(Function<V,U> f) { return (t,v) -> apply(t, f.apply(v)); }` in the `BiFunction` interface, but unfortunately, we don’t.

Answer (score 0):

```
int k = mulfunc.andThen(divfunc).andThen(sumfunc).andThen(subdunc).apply(6);
System.out.println(k);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but include an explanation what this code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality and more likely to attract upvotes.